# How to generate only alphanumeric string using Auto Fixure

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, xunit

I am using xUnit for unit testing in which I am using Autofixure to generate random strings. But in my API code, I am not allowing special characters as input to method hence test case is failing. Is there way to generate only alphanumeric string in auto fixure.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it without using auto fixure using below code.

```
 public string GenerateAlphanumericString(int size)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            const string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

            char[] chars = new char[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                chars[i] = Alphabet[rand.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
            }
            return new string(chars);
        }
```